# Mouse clicker program without autohotkey?

Tags: python

I am a total programming newb and am trying to find a way to automate a mouse click once every 5 seconds for 5 minutes at a specific location to automatically run a licensed program many times. My work computer does not allow installation of autohotkey, but I was able to install Python v3.5 (v2.7 will not install). My work computer uses windows 7 and can't install any programs that require admin rights.

I tried using the PyAutoGui module and it does not appear to be working with v3.5 python?

The script i want to use is something like below, but the script below is for v2.5 python, which I cannot use on v3.5. Can someone translate this script to v3.5 python?

```
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):

    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

click(10,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a Python script that would open and close the program using [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)?

```
import subprocess, time

def run_program():
    program = subprocess.Popen("path/to/file.exe")
    program.terminate()

while True:
    run_program()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

[PyAutoGui is compatible with Python 3](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tests.html).

Here is a short Python 3 program that will constantly print out the position of the mouse cursor:

```
#! python3
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

To perform mouse even by move pointer to 100x200, then click the left mouse button:

```
pyautogui.click(x=100, y=200)
```

Few other examples:

```
>>> pyautogui.click(clicks=2)  # double-click the left mouse button
>>> pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.25)  # double-click the left mouse button, but with a quarter second pause in between clicks
>>> pyautogui.click(button='right', clicks=3, interval=0.25)  ## triple-click the right mouse button with a quarter second pause in between clicks
```

See: [Mouse Control Functions](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html).